# Martial artist ally of Doctor Strange in a Spider-Man cartoon

Tags: marvel, character-identification, spider-man, doctor-strange

This character appeared in an episode of the early-mid '90s Spider-Man cartoon, specifically the episode where Spider-Man teams up with Strange to stop Strange's enemy Mordo and rescue Mary Jane from a cult Mordo leads.

The character I'm looking for is a martial artist skilled with a sword (he wields two of them against the villains)- while I don't remember his name I seem to recall his voice was provided by George Takei.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[According to IMDB](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112175/characters/nm0001786), George Takei portrayed [Wong](https://marvelanimated.fandom.com/wiki/Wong) -- Dr. Strange's assistant -- in *Spider-Man: The Animated Series*.

Wong is briefly visible at the 0:16 mark in the clip below.

In the comics, [Wong](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Wong_(Earth-616)) is also a martial artist who's given Dr. Strange some instruction in the arts.

[image]

<sub>*[Doctor Strange, Sorcerer Supreme #41](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Strange,_Sorcerer_Supreme_Vol_1_41)*</sub>

Comment: This answer is so Wong, it must be right.